# .net 2.0 IRC component

Tags: .net, irc

Anyone know of a good winforms IRC component? I don't want an IRC application, I want to be able to add IRC functionality to an existing windows form

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/giladlavian/archive/2007/10/07/c-irc-client-api.aspx) and [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartirc4net/). You may need to build the UI component yourself but a good IRC library will take a lot of the heavy lifting out of the task.